# When compiling Specflow project - generation error reported

Tags: specflow

I am creating a new Specflow project in VS2017. I have added 1 rule in the features file and generated the initial steps code. However, when I attempt to build the project I get the following 2 errors.
(1) CS1029  #error: 'Generation error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
(2) Custom tool error: Generation error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Feature file contains,

```
Feature: Change_Theme_Change_Scheme

@Change_Theme_Change_Scheme
Scenario: Verfy change of scheme
    Given I log into Admin site
    And I navigate to Colour Scheme page
    And I select the Kumho theme
    When I click the Save Theme button
    Then Check website main menu background is Red
```

Steps file contains,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
namespace Tyres_and_Service_Tester.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class Change_Theme_Change_Scheme
        {
        [Given(@"I log into Admin site")]
        public void GivenILogIntoAdminSite()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
        [Given(@"I navigate to Colour Scheme page")]
        public void GivenINavigateToColourSchemePage()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
        [Given(@"I select the Kumho theme")]
        public void GivenISelectTheKumhoTheme()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
        [When(@"I click the Save Theme button")]
        public void WhenIClickTheSaveThemeButton()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
        [Then(@"Check website main menu background is Red")]
        public void ThenCheckWebsiteMainMenuBackgroundIsRed()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
    }
}
```

Image of project references

[image]

I've not come across this before when building Specflow projects with earlier versions of VS, and cannot figure out what I've done differently
Many thanks for any help. Tony

Comment: did you try run VS as administrator?

Comment: What kind of project did you use in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please also post your app.config

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your responses. I decided to start from scratch again adding the Specflow packages to VS, and recreating the features, steps etc. As you might of guessed it worked this time - so I'm at a loss what might of been going on. Anyway this question can be closed.